# How to boot USB in UEFI mode?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

we recently bought a new windows 8 laptop, and we are trying to install Ubuntu to it in a dual boot configuration. I downloaded the 64 bit 12.10 iso and put it in a USB stick, both with the utility recommended from the Ubuntu installation guide and with Unetbootin. 
However, when I reboot the laptop and select from BIOS the USB as first option, it just flashes the Toshiba logo for 2 seconds and then reboots again and does this ad infinitum (I disabled SecureBoot) until I remove the usb stick and then it boots normally into windows. If I however turn on the option CSM/legacy boot in the BIOS I CAN boot into the usb installer, so I don't think it is an issue with the usb stick nor the iso image.

The question is, how do I get it to boot in UEFI mode? Or should I just keep going in legacy mode and hope the installer recognizes the UEFI boot?

Comment: I have not tried this, which is why this is a comment not an answer, but there is a long discussion [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).  Try it if it works you can summarize the process as an answer and earn some reputation too.

Comment: You could also see if a firmware update is available for your computer. Such updates sometimes fix problems like the one you've described, although that's far from guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended up installing it in CSM/Compatibility mode. It didn't boot. But then using the Ubuntu version with BootRepair as a Live USB disk I ran BootRepair and it installed the EFI files and changed the booting mode and it worked. I still have no idea why it didn't work from the beginning.